# Game Center Host

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

I am currently creating a Game Center game, and am using the peer-to-peer functionality available. However, I would like to select one of the players (2 players) to act as a host, to ensure synchronization.

What is the best way to select a host (even randomly) from the players available and ensure that the other device knows which host was chosen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-12) is a nice, simple tutorial with code that demonstrates how to do this. They randomly choose one of the peers to be the host. Hope that Helps!

Comment: Thanks, the random number trick should work :). I guess I'd been so immersed in trying to find a constant and persistent playerID-like string, then comparing that, that I didn't even come close to thinking that. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

already posted answer , still here is sample code to do that thing

```
NSString *uid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
CoinTossID = [uid hash];
```

now in delegate Function

```
- (void)match:(GKMatch *)match didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPlayer:(NSString *)playerID
    {
        NSMutableArray *ReceivedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        ReceivedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
        int flag = [[ReceivedArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
        [ReceivedArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];

        int CoinValue = [ReceivedCoinTossID intValue];
        if(CoinValue > CoinTossID)
        {
           isPlayer1 = YES;
        }
        else
        {
              isPlayer1 = NO;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, using the device id should work too. However, note that [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier] is deprecated in iOS 5. Perhaps using [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].playerID would work better.